# Search button value/id and add a Class to it

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

How can I search a button by it's `id` or `Value` using jquery?

if `textbox = button value`,  I want to add a Class to it.

Button and their ID's are inside database and looped to display

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to an element of a particular ID you can do the following:

```
$('#cake').addClass("myClass");
```

Where `cake` is the ID of the element you want to change and `myClass` is the class you want to add to that ID.